# ASP.NET Core API Swagger behind EnvoyProxy swagger.json not found

Tags: swagger, envoyproxy

New to envoy proxy, i have a simple ASP.Net Core API with openapi/swagger and its containerized. There is envoy proxy that is calling the controller which works perfectly. But when swagger ui is being access from envoy proxy swagger.json is not found:

[image]

envoy config is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must set external url into swagger config:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/application/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1 Docs");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate, you need to use path base.

```
service.UsePathBase("/application")
```

If you want to know [more](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-pathbase-in-aspnetcore/)...

Pathbase refers to the base path of a URL. It is the part of the URL that comes after the domain name and before the query string or any additional path segments. For example, in the URL "https://example.com/users/123", the pathbase would be "/users/".